# "execv" child process existance and termination 

Tags: c, unix, process, exec

[popen() alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743771/popen-alternative) - I am using the `accepted` answer (pipe/fork/exec method) to solve my issue. Only difference is, instead of `execl`, I am using `execv`.

Now, my question is, does parent process have any control over child process created by `execv`? Lets say this whole sequence suggested in `accepted` answer is for tailing 1 file and I have many such files; I put this whole sequence in a function and if I call this function many times, at a point in time, is it possible to have many child `tail` processes around?

What I want to know is, 
1) Can I have multiple child processes running at any point in time?
2) how does child processes (created by execv) terminate? after `execv` call does parent know when child process (created by execv) is done/terminated? - answered.

Comment: If you are able to use it, GLib has a bombproof implementation of this stuff: http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-Spawning-Processes.html It is pretty difficult to get it all right (I know because I wrote the GLib one, of course it may not be all right still, but it handles a ton of details)

Comment: The phrase "child process created by execv" is incorrect.  execv does not create a child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a pipe from the child's stdout, you can often avoid signal/wait aggravation by just watching for the pipe to get EOF. You still have to reap the child to avoid zombies though http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process (if you don't care about the child's exit status, this is normally done with a double fork so you run your real subprocess as a grandchild and reap the intermediate child). The GLib code is the most complex possible example probably: http://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/glib/gspawn.c#n1191

Comment: If the child judiciously closes all fds, you're outta luck.

Comment: Often the whole point is to capture the child's stdout, so it's safe to assume it will either not close stdout, or that if it does, you're done with it anyhow. If your goal is something other than slurping the child's output, then you aren't in the "often" case, of course.

Comment: @Havoc P: Thanks for responding. I am on `FreeBSD`. My problem is, I am using this pipe/fork/exec method and I am seeing a lot of zombies at a point in time - that fills up my processes table (this is a low-end box) and thats why I am killing my main parent process and getting out of the program. Now, some thing is creating a lot of child processes inside my main program (parent process). But I am not sure how that is possible. But when the fork() fails, (because of max proc) and at that time I see a lot of <defunct> with parent as the main process. How can I trace this back to who culprit?

Comment: @jørgensen Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: zombies are because someone didn't waitpid their child ... you basically have to stare at the code and find the missing cleanups. or use the intermediate child approach to avoid the need to reap later.

Answer (score 3):

Execl and execv behave the same way.  [The only difference is how you specify the argument vector](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/execl.3.asp).  The "l" functions take the argument vector as a comma-delimited list.  E.g.,

```
execl("/bin/ls", "/bin/ls", "-r", "-t", "-l", NULL);
```

The "v" funtcions take the argument vector as an actual vector.  E.g.,

```
char *args[] = {"/bin/ls", "-r", "-t", "-l", NULL };
execv("/bin/ls", args);
```

See [here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ForkExecProcesses.html) or [here](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node22.html) for info about process control in C.

In general, a child process terminates when it's finished executing.  The parent, or other processes, can kill the child at any time.  A parent can use the waitpid() function to wait until a child has finished executing or to check if a child has finished executing.

Answer (score 2):

The parent receives a [`SIGCHLD`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGCHLD) signal.

Comment: Thanks Oli. In the whole sequence, can I do it in such a way that even if I need to do tail (or any other command for that matter) for 10 (for example) files, I do it one after another. I do not want to have more than 1 child process alive at any point in time. Is that possible?

Comment: thanks Oli. I have another probably a little different question: when I do `kill` on the child, does it release all the resources right away? does process table of OS knows about its death immediately?

Comment: if you kill a process, yes, all of its resources will be released by the operatin system except for an entry in the process table containing the child's return value.  the child is considered then to be a zombie.  your parent should "reap" the child process by using wait(), which will collect its return value and release the process table entry.  if your parent process dies before it reaps its children, init will do the reaping for it.  see the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353079/reaping-zombie-process-child